# Aspose.Pdf Polish Characters

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.pdf

Why my pdf don't display polish character?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Pdf pdf = new Pdf(ms);
Section section = pdf.Sections.Add();
var txt = new Text("aąbcćde");
txt.TextInfo.FontName = "calibri";
section.Paragraphs.Add(txt);
pdf.Close();
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
return bytes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those special characters are Unicode characters, so you have to make sure that your font supports them and call `pdf.SetUnicode();` before `pdf.Close`.

Comment: Ok this work. Other problem: how add custom font? i try use this code: `txt.TextInfo.TruetypeFontFileName = _serverPath + "//Assets//PdfFonts//calibri.ttf"; txt.TextInfo.FontName = "calibri";` but not work

Comment: I'm not sure if the font matching is case sensitive but if it is, you could try this: `txt.TextInfo.FontName = "Calibri";`. Otherwise I suggest you to look at the [documentation](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Fonts+embedding+while+creating+PDF) to read more about fonts and embedding them.

Comment: I'm using the new API in `Aspose.Pdf`, the `Document` class doesn't have `SetUnicode()` method. Any idea?